# How can I add an additional IP / hostname to my Kubernetes certificate?

Tags: kubernetes, ssl

I've recently followed [this guide](https://medium.com/nycdev/k8s-on-pi-9cc14843d43) to set up Kubernetes on my local Raspberry Pi cluster. I can access it fine on my LAN; however I'd like to be able to access it remotely as well. I've already set up port forwarding on my router, but when I try to connect from outside the LAN, I get a x509 certificate error indicating that the certificate is signed for my local 192.168 address but not for my home's IP. I could bypass this with the `--insecure-skip-tls-verify` options but I'd much rather have the certificate used simply incorporate my IP address. Only... I'm not fully sure how to do that, though I do have some ideas.

When I initially set things up with `kubeadm init`, should I have used the `--apiserver-advertise-address` option to specify my home IP? Would doing so have had any adverse effects (such as precluding my local/192.168 IP?). Ideally I'd like the certificate to be signed for both the internal and external IPs. Or is there some other option I should have given to `kubeadm init`? Secondly, now that it has been initialized, is there any way to regenerate the certificate and swap it out, or will I need to nuke the cluster?

To clarify, I don't have any certificate managers installed. I'm not talking about Ingress. I'm talking about the actual "root" certificate (for lack of a better term) that kubeadm generates when first installing the cluster, i.e. the one that lives at `/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To do this, you’ll first need your `kubeadm` configuration file. This creates a file named `kubeadm.yaml`:

`kubectl -n kube-system get configmap kubeadm-config -o jsonpath='{.data.ClusterConfiguration}' > kubeadm.yaml`

Now open the file in an editor, and find the `certSANs` list under the `apiServer` section. If it does not exist, you’ll need to add it; if so, you’ll just add another entry to that list. Example:

```
apiServer:
  certSANs:
  - "172.29.50.162"
  - "k8s.domain.com"
  - "other-k8s.domain.net"
  extraArgs:
    authorization-mode: Node,RBAC
  timeoutForControlPlane: 4m0s
```

Now move the old certificates to another folder, otherwise `kubeadm` will not recreate new ones:

`mv /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.{crt,key} ~`

Use `kubeadm` to generate new apiserver certificates:

`kubeadm init phase certs apiserver --config kubeadm.yaml`

Now restart your *kubeapiserver* container:

1. Run `docker ps | grep kube-apiserver | grep -v pause` to get the
   container ID for the container running the Kubernetes API server
2. Run `docker kill <containerID>` to kill the container.
3. *The Kubelet will automatically restart the container, which will pick up the new certificate.*

If everything is working as expected, don't forget to update the `kubeadm` ConfigMap stored in the cluster, otherwise, future `kubeadm` upgrade will be lacking your new config:

If using Kubernetes < v1.15:

`kubeadm config upload from-file --config kubeadm.yaml`

For Kubernetes version >= [v1.15](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.15.md#deprecations-and-removals):

`kubeadm init phase upload-config kubeadm --config kubeadm.yaml`

*This article has a more complete guide on how to [Adding a Name to the Kubernetes API Server Certificate](https://blog.scottlowe.org/2019/07/30/adding-a-name-to-kubernetes-api-server-certificate/)*

Comment: Worked like a charm! Only one thing to note: the `from-file` option you specified at the end is actually deprecated. The new command to upload that file is `kubeadm init phase upload-config kubeadm --config=kubeadm.yaml` Thank you!

Comment: @soapergem Thanks for noting! The answer was updated with the new command.

Comment: This worked really well. just one quick update: on Kubernetes v1.22.3 I did not have to restart the apiserver for the new certs to be used

Comment: This did not work for me. I cannot generate the kubeadm.yaml because the wrong IP in in my cert! Is there a way to generate it without a connection to the apiserver on port 6443?

Answer (score 2):

The answer given by @Eduardo Baitello is the correct answer for the vast majority of Kube installs. However I learned that if you've installed the MicroK8S snap install on Ubuntu the instructions are a little bit different. Per [this issue](https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/421), you'll need to update the `/var/snap/microk8s/current/certs/csr.conf.template` file, then run `microk8s.stop` and `microk8s.start` in succession.